# What is the correct combination of number and length of the spokes to go bowfishing?

Tags: wheels, identify-this-bike, reuse

I have seen that it is possible to build a bow starting from two 26" wheels.
See [the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pvlrky1BS0)

I am wondering what is the correct length of the spokes and what is the best number of spokes to achieve a comfortable and reliable bow.

I would appreciate also if someone can identify this rim:

[image]

Comment: Downvoters: please comment how can I improve the question.

I honestly hope to derail the google algorithm, the SE (SE stands obviously for shameless exaggerated) exploitation of users, the gamification of the sharing of knowledge.

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a stunt question.

Comment: @AdamRice where can I find the definition of stunt question?

Comment: Might be more on topic on Great Outdoors, or I see that Sports has an archery tag, https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archery  As does Martial Arts, https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archery

Comment: Today is May 28th, not April 1st?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! This question is off-topic, but here are a few suggestions: 1. Use a 700c rim, because that is the widest commonly available rim size. 2. Use a steel rim, rather than carbon fiber or aluminum, because steel has better bending properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice how in the video he removes all the spokes with an angle grinder and we never see them again. then he chops up the rim into four pieces, which has the effect of making it come apart a bit. On that basis, it would seem, to this non-fisher, that the spoke count and length is entirely immaterial.

You say it is a 26 inch rim, it looks like it might be about 20 mm wide, so not super wide. probably the width doesn't matter anyway. The wheel diameter will affect the length of the four pieces, so presumably a bigger wheel size will give more leverage in the bow and a slightly lighter action. but not by a whole lot.

Pick a wheel that looks a little bit like the one in the video and you'll be golden.

Comment: Thanks, this was quite focused! However I am still waiting for mister 36-spokes to chip in...